# ¿Cómo calcular la posición de los elementos de una página para formatear el CSS3?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Quisiera saber cómo hacen calcular la posición y tamaño que deben tener los elementos de una página web que se desarrolla desde cero, para formatear correctamente el CSS3.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

- Principalmente **hacer un esquema básico**, ya sea en base a un diseño o un wireframe.
- Seguir los **lineamientos de tamaños de bootstrap o las guías de diseño de android y/o ios**, es recomendable.
- Hoy día, no se debe posicionar usando medidas absolutas, **sino usando porcentajes**, debido a las distintas resoluciones.
- También te recomiendo **usar medidas** **`em`** y **`rem`**, ya que al depender del `font-family` y el `font-size`, **evitas problemas de escalado y de cambios inesperados al cambiar la tipografía**. Pero usando estas medidas más que nada en definir limitaciones y relaciones de espacio entre un elemento y otro, es decir, aplicándolo en `margin`, `padding`, `line-height`, `letter-spacing`, etc. Algunos prefieren usar solo **`rem`**, porque depende de una única medida y es la del `font-size` y `font-family` aplicado al body.
- Ten en cuenta, que  **también existen medidas como** **`vmin`**, **`vmax`**, **`vh`** y **`vw`**, que son relativas al tamaño y proporción del dispositivo que donde se visualice el diseño. Son de uso especial, sobretodo porque dan mucho juego en cuanto un posicionamiento y tamaños dinámico, ya sea usandolas tal cual o combinandolas con **"funciones de css"** como **`calc`**.

Comment: No estoy muy de acuerdo, usar porcentajes en vez de medidas absolutas no es muy recomendable, los porcentajes los usas mas en los grids. Al acomodar elementos absolutos (por dar un ejemplo) es mejor usar px o incluso rems ya que estos se posicionan en base a su padre.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo contigo, si bien es cierto que se usan más en los grids, pero es por una razón y porque (y es mi opinión) uno debería solo posicionar elementos usando grids. Ahora en el caso de acomodar elementos absolutos, lo mismo usar porcentajes y no px o rems, por la sencilla razón de que hoy día todo debe ser posicionado pensando en multidispositivo, nunca he tenido un problema haciendo este tipo de cálculos, sino lo contrario, menos quebraderos de cabeza, calculando.

Comment: En cuanto a los **px** o **rems,** yo recomendaría más el uso de **em** y **rem** que pixeles y no para calcular la posición, sino límites, interlineados, paddings y márgenes. De hecho, me parece una buena observación, la voy a incluir en mi respuesta.

Comment: Es muy sencillo, si tu tienes un div al 50% y dentro de este div posicionas un elemento absoluto (obviamente siendo el padre relativo) el elemento hijo se alinearà segùn su padre aùn usando px, rems y/o ems. En el grid, si... usa porcentajes.